# child process doesn't exit

Tags: node.js, gulp

Following is my gulp task:

```
    httpServer.on("close", (code, signal) => {
      console.log(
        `child process terminated due to receipt of signal ${signal}, code ${code}`
      );
      console.log("httpServer close");
      resolve();
    })
  );
  await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2e3));
  httpServer.kill("SIGINT");
  await httpServerClose;
  console.log("here");
```

I got following output:

```
Available on:
  http://127.0.0.1:5001
  http://192.168.31.122:5001
  http://172.21.96.1:5001
  http://172.18.192.1:5001
Hit CTRL-C to stop the server

child process terminated due to receipt of signal SIGINT, code null
httpServer close
here

[13:32:57] Finished 'build:release' after 2.01 s
```

The problem is port 5001 is still in use.
I'm on windows 10, node v16.13.1

Answer (score 0):

`.kill()` doesn't guarantees that the process will successfully terminate. You may check for the resulting boolean that `kill()` returns, but that only indicates wheter the signal was delivered or not.

```
childProcess.on('close', (code, signal) => {
  console.log(
    `child process terminated due to receipt of signal ${signal}`);
});

// Send SIGHUP to process.
const signalDelivered = childProcess.kill('SIGHUP');
console.log(signalDelivered)
```

For some reason, the childProcess is still running / crashed or the SIGINT was not handled correctly.
My suggestion is that you implement "Graceful shutdown".

Remember, if in your childProcess code you are handling `process.on('SIGINT', ..)`,you need to close the server that is listening connections and then call process.exit(0).

```
const server = app.listen(5001)
process.on('SIGINT',function(){
  server.close(err => {
    //exit after server is not listening anymore
    process.exit(err ? 1 : 0)
  })
});
```

Comment: Hi Jone, I've edited my post a little bit, still can't find out the reason. the http-server is the public npm package `http-server`, it will exit when I type Ctrl + C. Since I've already send it SIGINT, I really have no idea, why it doesn't work.

Comment: In your second code example, what is `process` supposed to be?

Comment: @PhilippLudwig [process](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process) is a node global object.